# Design of xaml compatible all resolution

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I got a view and I try to make it compatible wih all resolutions for windows Phone.I know to do his I have to use "auto" value for margin, height,width rpoperties but I can't get the design i want...I pasted the xaml code...your help is welcome

[image]

```xaml
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF00485A">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contient le nom de l'application et le titre de la page-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
            <Image Width="180" Height="180" Source="/Images/BContact/ico_app-authent_bannuaire.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,90"></Image>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,10,12,0" >

        <StackPanel Background="#FF003A48"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,-10,12,0">
                <PasswordBox x:Name="Passwordtext" IsEnabled="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#55000000" Width="476"  MaxLength="6"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" PasswordChar="•" Height="106" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock  x:Name="entrezcodepin" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Entrez votre code PIN"  Foreground="White" FontSize="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>

        <!--ContentPanel - placez tout contenu supplémentaire ici-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,12,0"  >

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   Click="EnterPassword"></Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="5" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   Click="EnterPassword" ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="9" Background="White"  FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   Click="EnterPassword"></Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content=" " Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48" Click="EnterPassword" ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="2" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"  Click="EnterPassword"></Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="6" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"    Click="EnterPassword"></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="7" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"  Click="EnterPassword"></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="0" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"    Click="EnterPassword" ></Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="3" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"    Click="EnterPassword"></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="4" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   Click="EnterPassword"></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="8" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"    Click="EnterPassword"></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"  Background="White" Foreground="#55000000"   Click="EnterPassword">

                <Image Source="/Images/ico_action_delete-text.png" MaxHeight="54"  ></Image>

            </Button>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Where is the problem - that "enter password" should dissapear when you start entering chars?

Comment: I wanna achieve the Image I pasted...I can easy code this view with using margin,height and width value on each control but that's not the good solution because the result won't be compatible with other resolutions...There is no problem with the "enter password" ,the numeric pad is the problem the margin between each button is not good...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF00485A">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contient le nom de l'application et le titre de la page-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="/Images/BContact/ico_app-authent_bannuaire.png"></Image>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF003A48" >
            <PasswordBox x:Name="Passwordtext" IsEnabled="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#55000000" MaxLength="6"    PasswordChar="•"  />
            <TextBlock  x:Name="entrezcodepin" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Entrez votre code PIN"  Foreground="White" FontSize="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <!--ContentPanel - placez tout contenu supplémentaire ici-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   ></Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="5" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="9" Background="White"  FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   ></Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content=" " Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48" ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="2" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"  ></Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="6" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="7" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"  ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="0" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   ></Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="3" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="4" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"  ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="8" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   ></Button>

            <Button  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"  Background="White" Foreground="#55000000"  >

                <Image Source="/Images/ico_action_delete-text.png" Stretch="Fill" ></Image>

            </Button>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing concerns default `Padding` and `Margin` of Button's Style. For your purpose you should create your own button `Style`. An example can look like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Then your Button can look like this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" Background="White" FontSize="40" Foreground="#FF003A48"   Click="EnterPassword" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
```

You can freely set the `Margin` of each button for your purposes. I think this should work.